# How to move PS3 digital games to a Xbox One console

Tags: ps3, xbox-one, minecraft-legacy-console

So just today I got a Xbox One with only one game, I have spent my birthday money to get it all. The thing is, is that how will I be able to move my digital PS3 games to the Xbox One? I have Minecraft as my one of my PS3 digital games and I really wanna get it on my Xbox One to play with my school friends.

Comment: This doesn't seem possible. You **CAN** play Xbox 360 games on an Xbox One, but I don't think PlayStation 3 games can work on an Xbox One.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this. Playstation and Xbox are separate entities. Even if the games are digital, they are different in terms of code between the two platforms, and you also cannot get the licenses transferred between Playstation and Xbox. You will have to purchase the games again on your Xbox.